# PHP Division incorrect answer

Tags: php, decimal, division

I have a piece of code that worked perfectly and then just stopped:

```
    $miccpl = $micbudgetspent / $micleads;
    echo $micbudgetspent . " / " . $micleads . " = " . $miccpl;
    if ($micleads != NULL)
    {
        echo "$ " . round($miccpl, 2);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "TBA";
    }
```

This is the result:

> 2 000 / 49 = 0.040816326530612$ 0.04

Why is it giving me 0.0408? When it supposed to be 40.80

Comment: Is it literally `2 000` (with a space)? That's not a number, but will be cast to the number 2 if you try and divide it.

Comment: I think Iainn has found your issue, 2 / 49 = 0.0408163265306122. Remove the space between the 2 and 000

Comment: So it was not working perfectly, it just had not been properly tested.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the value of `$micbudgetspent` is the string `'2 000'`.

In the statement:

```
$miccpl = $micbudgetspent / $micleads;
```

`$micbugdetspent` is [converted to a number](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) (it is an operand of the [division operator `/`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)).

Because of the space after `2`, the conversion produces `2` as the value to be used further in the expression and the value of `2 / 49` is `0.040816326530612`

Read about the [conversion from strings to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) in PHP.